# Old software in the Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: linux-mint, synaptic

I'm new to Linux and I like using Mint 17, but I don't understand why the Synaptic Package Manager doesn't have the most recent software.  For example Eclipse 4.5 is available, but the manage only has 3.x, which was released about 3 years ago.  I want to install the most recent things, but looking up how to for each program is a bit of a hassle for someone who's technical experience is about 98% on Windows.

So, why doesn't the manager have at least fairly recent updates and is there a reasonable solution (besides me magically learning about Linux overnight)?

Answer (score 2):

Reason - most distributions cannot update all packages straight away, as often they need to test each version, and sometimes specific patches need to make it work on the distribution. Also, with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (which Mint 17 is based on), the packages are supposed to be more stable vs being new and up to date. Third party developers sadly don't always offer the latest packages for most Linux distros as they are not always used as much as other OSs.

Solution - Eclipse is available as a pre-compiled tarball package which you can install by downloading from [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/). You can then follow the steps in [this answer on AU](https://askubuntu.com/a/145018/178596) to install it *(you need to get the package for you architecture - read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os) if you don't know it)*:

> If you've downloaded Eclipse from their official website, follow these
>   steps for the installation.
>
> 1. Extract the eclipse.XX.YY.tar.gz using
>
>    ```
>    tar -zxvf eclipse.XX.YY.tar.gz
>    ```
> 2. Become root and Copy the extracted folder to `/opt`
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv eclipse.XX.YY /opt
>    ```
> 3. Create a desktop file and install it:
>
>    ```
>    gedit eclipse.desktop
>    ```
>
>    and copy the following to the `eclipse.desktop` file.
>
>    ```
>    [Desktop Entry]
>    Name=Eclipse 
>    Type=Application
>    Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 eclipse44
>    Terminal=false
>    Icon=eclipse
>    Comment=Integrated Development Environment
>    NoDisplay=false
>    Categories=Development;IDE;
>    Name[en]=Eclipse
>    ```
>
>    then execute the following command to automatically install it in the unity:
>
>    ```
>    sudo desktop-file-install eclipse.desktop
>    ```
> 4. Create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` using
>
>    ```
>    sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse44
>    ```
> 5. For eclipse icon to be displayed in dash, eclipse icon can be added as
>
>    ```
>    sudo cp /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm
>    ```
> 6. Don't forget that you need to have either OpenJDK or Sun Java installed to be able to run eclipse. Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) for more
>      information about Java installation. Here is a simple example of
>      installing Open JDK 1.6:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
>    ```
> 7. Launch eclipse and then give it the required permissions to modify the osgi file:
>
>    ```
>    sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi
>    ```

With Ubuntu and similar systems, there are also sometimes [PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) available which often have newer versions of some software available - in this case I can only find [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~eclipse-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) which only has version 3.7.